# Windows 8.1+Debian 7.7 (GRUB) Dual Boot across two SSDs not allowing restoration of MBR for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, debian, ssd, grub

I've tried too many different things to list, but I'll explain the main ones.

**SSD 1** => **Windows 8.1** (Primary Boot in BIOS)

**SSD 2** => **Debian 7.7**

**GRUB** is currently in place as bootloader.

I've attempted many times to delete the partitions/volumes for **Debian** on **SSD 2**, and to restore the **Windows bootloader** via installation disc command prompt or USB repair drive via command prompt.

If I delete the volumes on **SSD 2** containing **Debian/GRUB**, I cannot boot **Windows 8.1**, and it takes me to a **GRUB rescue** in which it says the drive could not be found. I can only boot to **Windows 8.1** again once I've re-installed **Debian/GRUB**.

Once I'm in command prompt, I do the following:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /scanos
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd

(also tried bootrec without .exe, and without the space)
```

Most times, `/fixboot` and `/rebuildbcd` return `Element not found`, and `/scanos` returns an incorrect detection of Windows installations. I've used Diskpart to List Partitions and mark the Windows partitions as Active again, which enabled me to use `/fixboot` and `/rebuildbcd`, but they did not actually work in restoring the MBR.

I've read many different guides and Questions/Answers on this, however almost every single one applies to both operating systems being on the same drive. Certain guides even mention it being very different when on separate drives, but do not actually provide a solution for that scenario.

I just want to restore **Windows bootloader**, and remove **Debian/GRUB** from **SSD 2**.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after much trial and error.

I did not have Secure Boot enabled in BIOS at any point originally, and then I tried enabling it, but also disabling it. Truthfully, I cannot remember if it was enabled when I managed to fix this.

By the best of my memory, I did the following.

1) Enable Secure Boot in BIOS

2) Ensure that the drive with Windows 8.1 was set to default boot

3) One time boot to Windows 8 installation disc and go to Command Prompt

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /scanos
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
YES
```

(You will probably find that /fixboot and rebuildbcd don't work and will probably return `Element not found`, and the times that they do, /rebuildbcd still encounters an error at Yes/No/All, but don't worry about that)

4) Now in Command Prompt, type:

```
DISKPART
LIST DISK
SELECT DISK # (select the one with Windows)
LIST PARTITION
SELECT PARTITION # (the biggest one that contains Windows, there should be one for 100MB and then one in GB for Windows)
ACTIVE
Exit
Exit
```

5) Attempt to use Diagnose/Repair from the same menu you found Command Prompt. It probably won't work, but that's okay.

6) Enter Command Prompt again, and type:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /scanos
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
YES
```

This should all work this time, with the message that it completed successfully. When you restart your computer, it should say that no operating system was found, and to use CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.

7) Now, one time boot from the Windows 8 installation disc again, and run Diagnose/Repair. It should actually work this time, and should boot you into Windows now using the Windows bootloader ignoring GRUB/Debian.

I apologize, but I cannot remember precisely what I did in what order, but I'm fairly sure it was this. I recommend trying this with both Secure Boot enabled and disabled, seeing as I can't remember which of the two I had.